# The flying colours

Tags: knowledge, visual, nonogram

Here's a $36\times36$ nonogram with two colours. Name all 12 things depicted in it.

Note that cells filled with different colours do not need to have a gap between them.

> [image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Pictured in the nonogram are ...

> ... the flags of Norway, the United States, Costa Rica, Japan, the Netherlands (or perhaps Luxembourg, given the shade of blue), Iceland, Cuba, France, Switzerland, Russia, the Dominican Republic and Czechia. (The title is a hint at flags.)

The nonogram:

> [image: Flags of the World]

Comment: Something's missing on rows 23-24 (the one with 2 11 7 3, plus the one below it). Otherwise looks correct.

Comment: Oh yes. I've been staring at the paintbucket tool for too long. (And I wondered why there weren't more stipes.) I'll fix.