# Captain Pun's new boat

Tags: word, knowledge, visual, grid-deduction, nonogram

My good friend Captain Pun has bought a new boat.

"And this is a picture of its sail!" he said, showing me this:

[image]
"Solve the nonogram and you'll soon know what type of boat it is!"

> Can you solve the two-colour nonogram to help me work out what type of boat he bought?

<sub>*This puzzle can be solved without guessing. Note that cells filled with different colours do not necessarily need to have a gap between them. Numbers marked in **bold** are **red**, while those in* normal *weight are* blue.</sub>

Comment: Ooh, I love this kind of puzzle. Wish I'd seen this one sooner.

Comment: @Randal'Thor I've got plans for a few more in the future, so hopefully you'll get your chance! :)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Finished nonogram:

> [image]

These are

> The flags of Finland, Laos, Austria, Georgia, Somalia, Honduras, Iceland and Peru.

Meaning the captain's new boat is literally a

> **FLAGSHIP**, as spelt by the first letters of the country names.

Comment: Quick work, jafe! (Although S is misidentified here at present...) It was only while posting that I spotted a similar inspiration was behind [one of your own puzzles](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/85868/the-flying-colours) from earlier in the year - so no wonder you nailed this one so speedily! +1 and the green checkmark imminent once that error is fixed :)

Comment: @Stiv Oops, should have at least single-checked that one... Fixed now!

Comment: Perfect! Well done :)