# Professor Pun's Personal Project

Tags: knowledge, visual, nonogram, humor

When I first met my good friend [Captain Pun](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/91626/captain-puns-new-boat), he invited me to dinner to meet his wife, a physics professor at the university. Over a glass of wine I inquired into her research interests.

"Let me show you!" she said, quickly scrawling the following onto a napkin:

[image]

"Solve the nonogram and you'll soon know what I spend all of my time studying! I'll give you a clue: you're looking for a two-word answer..."

> Can you solve the nonogram to help me work out Professor Pun's area of expertise?

<sub>*NB The nonogram can be solved without guessing.*</sub>

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Thanks to jafe for spotting this. I think the answer is

> Elementary Particles

Solved nonogram

> [image]

Reasoning

> The image represents two periodic tables with certain **elements** removed with chemical symbols (in order) P, Ar, Ti, Cl, Es which spells out **particles**

Comment: Kind of looks like rot13(gjb crevbqvp gnoyrf jvgu pregnva ryrzragf erzbirq)?

Comment: @jafe Great spot! Just could not see this at all.

Comment: Y'know what ignore all my comments I'm bad at reading

Comment: That's the one! Well done hexomino and @jafe. +1 and the green checkmark incoming :)

Answer (score 5):

Professor Pun studies

> quantum particles

The solved nonogram looks like this:

> [image]

If you

> split it in two, you get two periodic tables, with specific elements missing (highlighted in blue):
>
>  [image]
>
>  The missing elements are, in order, Phosphorus, Argon, Titanium, Chlorine, and Einsteinium, whose chemical symbols spell out the word P-Ar-Ti-Cl-Es. The fact that there are *two* period tables hints at quantum mechanics, and how it allows particles to be in two places at once, hence my final answer of "quantum particles".

I arrived at this answer independently of the commenters on hexomino's answer.

Comment: +1 for the solve and thought process behind your answer. Afraid there's no 'quantum' involved here (really I was looking for a pun...) - the reason I used two was merely to ensure the letters appeared in order (rather than just using one and resorting to an anagram). Well done though - I like the quantum discussion points :)