# Party Time with Captain Pun

Tags: knowledge, visual, grid-deduction, nonogram, humor

The other day my good friend [Captain Pun](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/91626/captain-puns-new-boat) invited me to a party on board his new boat.

"What will the dress code be?" I asked.

Captain Pun said he'd email me the details. Later that day I received the following image in my inbox:

[image]

The accompanying message said only: "Solve the nonogram, then come dressed accordingly!"

> Can you solve the three-colour nonogram to help me work out what I should wear to the party?

<sub>*This puzzle can be solved without guessing. Note that cells filled with different colours do not necessarily need to have a gap between them. Numbers marked in **bold** are **black**, numbers in (circles) are (red), and those in* normal *weight are* grey.</sub>

Comment: Yayyy, I got to this one in time!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Completed nonogram grid:

> [image]

This is (thanks @msh210 !)

> a Cluedo board,
>
>  [image]

and

> the heart is in the LOUNGE,

so the dress code must be

> LOUNGE SUIT.

Edited to add:

> the puzzle is even more clever than I'd realised. The heart isn't just an arbitrary symbol: it represents one of the SUITS in card games. So both the words "lounge" and "suit" are clued (no pun intended) in the image!

Comment: rot13(Pbzr qerffrq jvgu lbhe urneg va gur evtug cynpr?) - alternatively, there are rot13(9 juvgr frpgvbaf, fb "Pbzr qerffrq gb gur 9?")

Comment: Looks like it _might_ (I'd have to check) be a Clue board. If so, presumably it's a play on the name of whatever room that is.

Comment: @msh210 You're right - that's the rot13(Ybhatr).

Comment: @msh210 Ahhh, wow, that makes perfect sense! Thank you! I knew that pattern, especially the middle part, was ringing a bell somewhere.

Comment: Would've been funny if rot13(gur oebxra jvaqbj-ybbxvat fghss + gur urneg jnf "oernx zl urneg")

Comment: I spotted a few missing blanks in your completed nonogram. Your 25th row (next to bottom) is missing the 'inner' black 1s.

Comment: Also: Here is an image with the correct rotation so it matches the nonogram:

https://i.pinimg.com/originals/76/a2/4f/76a24fda5952a89008dcb15ae71df4ef.jpg

Comment: @Somebody How could I miss that? Those are literally the easiest ones to fill! To your second comment: I thought I'd leave a mental pi-radian rotation as an exercise for the reader :-)

Comment: lol yep! I finished the nonogram and went to check yours and that's the only difference I noticed!

Comment: @Somebody Aww, you did all that work to finish it and still got ninja'd to posting an answer? :-(

Comment: nah I was a good 8-10 minutes behind. I grabbed the nonogram before you answered but you probably posted right after I saw the post so you're good!

Comment: TIL that Clue is called "Cluedo" in areas outside of North America

Comment: @Quintec It's called Clue over there? I'd assumed msh210's comment was typoed!

Comment: @Randal'Thor and I thought your answer was typoed until I looked it up! :P

Comment: Hooray, all correct - well done! +1 and the green checkmark incoming :)

Comment: Although it will be obvious to most, any chance you could just rot13(oevrsyl zragvba gur yvax orgjrra URNEG naq FHVG) - for some it may not be immediately apparent! Thanks :)

Comment: @Stiv Oooh, that wasn't apparent even to me! I thought that shape was just meant to indicate the important spot.