# Captain Pun's favourite animals

Tags: knowledge, visual, grid-deduction, nonogram, humor

My good friend [Captain Pun's party](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/91903/party-time-with-captain-pun) was a truly excellent event. His new boat - the venue - was a beautiful thing to behold, decorated throughout with nonograms in frames (as anybody who knows him might well expect).

I spent rather a long time admiring one in particular:
[image]
"Ah!" spoke Captain Pun from beside me. "My favourite animals... Solve the nonogram, say what you see, and you'll learn which two-word sea creatures are my absolute favourites!"

> Can you solve the two-colour nonogram to help me work out the Captain's favourite animals?

<sub>*This puzzle can be solved without guessing. Note that cells filled with different colours do not necessarily need to have a gap between them. Numbers in (**bold circles**) are (**blue**), while those in* normal *weight are* black.</sub>

Comment: Is it possible to solve this online?

Comment: @Stiv I guess what it means is some web/mobile-friendly version of the puzzle (like using http://puzz.link) so no need to rewrite on excel or paper.

Comment: I mean, I don’t have access to paper etc. So I thought if I could do it on my phone, like here https://www.puzzle-nonograms.com

Comment: @Jdrupal I see - fine to do it on something like MS Paint using the fill tool, or recreating it in another form (Excel, a web tool, etc.). I would naturally advise against any kind of automated 'brainless' solve (that seems rather against the spirit of the puzzle) but no need to print off and scan in a solution if you have a way to do it all electronically... Does that answer your question now? Good luck :)

Comment: Thank you. I don’t have time to copy it over. It was just if you had created it using some kind of electronic tool. Then there would maybe be a way to solve it online. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: @Jdrupal Aha, I get you now! 'Fraid I created it in Excel, so sorry no web link that I can provide you with this time. Will consider it for future use - thanks for the idea... :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is the solved nonogram:

> [image]

The image shows:

> A map of the British Isles, with **Wales** highlighted in **blue**.

Thus, Captain Pun's favorite animals are

> BLUE WHALES

Comment: That's the one! Well done :) +1 The green checkmark will be yours if you can fix the one small error in the second line up from the bottom (your '1' square is in the wrong place...)

Comment: d'oh! should be fixed now!

Comment: Perfect :) The checkmark is yours!